# Solve:$e^{-y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + e^{-x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = e^{x+y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve:

$$e^{-y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + e^{-x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = e^{x+y}$$
Thi is the first PDE I tried to solve after studying a little bit about PDE and Fourier series. I think we can do it using Lagrange method. Am I right?

Comment: To solve your problem, you should use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: It is possible to find the general solution with the method of characteristic or another method. But the calculus is too complicated for someone who has studied only " a little bit about PDE". I guess that there is typo in your equation. For example $$e^{-y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + e^{-x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = e^{-x-y}$$ would be more convenient for beginners.